# Can we get the current logged in user's id in Marketing cloud script activity?

Tags: marketing-cloud

I want to run the script based on the logged in user. So can i get the logged in user's id inside my script activity? If yes, what is the syntax to be used?

Answer (score 1):

Your script activities are not running in the context of the user, but in system context. Meaning there can be multiple users logged into the system when a script activity is executed in Automation Studio, making it impossible to pass any user identification into a variable within your SSJS.